# align images horizontally with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, spectre.css

I want to make an image slider with thumbnail images to select from, my idea is allign all images horizontally and hide overfolwn than with javascript i will just change the left postion to display the needed thumbnail, but I couldn't figure out how to css images to align hrizontally and hide the part that goes beyond the container of the thumnails, I am using [spectre](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/index.html) css framework, my HTML looks like this

```css
.img-list {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .img-list {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

.img-container {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-main {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-main img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-exp.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-icons.min.css">

<div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column col-md-12">
          <div class="img-main">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="img-list ">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iZ3Lww/img2.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQsPOb/img3.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFFdib/img4.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hS5ppG/img5.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/goKtGw/img6.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bSWjOb/img7.jpg">
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i2o9pG/img8.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-md-12">
          <h1>Peugeaut 206</h1>
          <input type="number" onchange="showImage(this)" value="1">
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam culpa sint recusandae architecto odit tenetur
            fugit rerum soluta quidem velit. Eos provident nemo dolores vitae pariatur perspiciatis delectus ex dignissimos!
            Quibusdam architecto natus nam ullam cupiditate deserunt voluptatem nulla inventore nesciunt error recusandae
            quod ab, harum temporibus laboriosam numquam facilis beatae. Numquam odit dolorem quasi rerum aut cupiditate
            distinctio ad! Assumenda aut, repellat nihil, fugit doloremque doloribus harum possimus commodi aliquam recusandae
            reiciendis delectus vel modi quia sapiente sit voluptas deleniti. Repellat magni rerum fuga vitae odio ad
            ullam tempora.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `white-space:nowrap`

```css
.img-list {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /*Show horizontal scroll*/
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .img-list {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

.img-container {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  white-space:nowrap; /*Added this*/
}

.img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /*to remove unwanted whitespace */
  position: relative;
}

.img-main {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-main img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-main">
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-list ">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iZ3Lww/img2.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQsPOb/img3.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFFdib/img4.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hS5ppG/img5.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/goKtGw/img6.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bSWjOb/img7.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i2o9pG/img8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I make the adjacent div not affected by the white-space:nowrap, because it is making an adjacent div to go to the nex line

Comment: I have edited the question, you can find the complete code, thanks for your help

Comment: @AnaHoua am pretty sure it has nothing to do with whitespace nowrap ...  and in your code we cannot see the issue as you are missing the framework part. Can you show me a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: look here: https://codepen.io/mehdi-coding/pen/LdzyEJ, try to remove white-space:nowrap and you will see that the two divs will be adjacent

Comment: @AnaHoua well, the two divs are already adjacent for me with the white-space nowrap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167546/discussion-between-ana-houa-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is good option but if you want you can add to div  with a list of thumbnail images `white-space: nowrap`

Here is jsfiddle:

```css
.img-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-list {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-main img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-main">
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-list ">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iZ3Lww/img2.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQsPOb/img3.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFFdib/img4.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hS5ppG/img5.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/goKtGw/img6.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bSWjOb/img7.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i2o9pG/img8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have updated CSS removed the unnecessary style.

Answer (score 0):

My solution of choice is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

To class `.img-container`:

1. add `display: flex;` - this turns the container into a flex container
2. add `flex-direction: row;` - this is default but illustrates the example
3. add `flex-wrap: nowrap;` - this is also default but also illustrates the example
4. finally, change `overflow` to `hidden`

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/psmg3af7/4/)

I believe this achieves what you desire. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: indeed iy works, but I am using spectre css, when I add flex to img-container all the layout will be broken https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/index.html